# inequality on prime gaps

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If we have an admissible set $H = \{h_{1}, \dots , h_{k}\}$ of integers that is fixed. Then if one can show there are infinitely many $n$ such that at least $j$ of the translates $n+h_{1}, \dots, n+h_{k}$ are prime then the following inequality holds:

$$ \lim\inf_{n}(p_{n+j-1} - p_{n}) \leq \max_{r,s}|h_{r} - h_{s}|$$

Apparently this should be an obvious fact, but i'm not quite seeing how it follows...

Comment: What is the definition of max ? of liminf ? maybe that will help you.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee the definition of max is the largest value. The definition of liminf is the $\liminf_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = \sup_{n \geq 0}\inf_{m \geq n}x_{m}$.